# CentOS 7 httpd modules missing

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, centos7, yum, httpd

Finally I decided to migrate CentOS 5 to 7 but I can't get the httpd modules from yum or within the server.

I read that we can't blindly use `apache 2.2` config with `2.4` and module names might been changed or removed. How do I figure out what has it changed to?

How do I get the modules from yum? yum whatprovides mod_authz_default.so returns no package.

I keep commenting out one by one, it'll list out the next one. Yes there are modules in /usr/lib64/httpd/modules but not the ones that old httpd.conf needs.

```
Mar 01 16:25:01 myhost httpd[19931]: httpd: Syntax error on line 164 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_authn_default.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_authn_default.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Mar 01 16:25:01 myhost systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 01 16:25:01 myhost kill[19933]: kill: cannot find process ""
Mar 01 16:25:01 myhost systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 01 16:25:01 myhost systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Mar 01 16:25:01 myhost systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Mar 01 16:25:01 myhost systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Mar 01 16:39:25 myhost systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Mar 01 16:39:25 myhost httpd[20172]: httpd: Syntax error on line 170 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_authz_default.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_authz_default.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Mar 01 16:39:25 myhost systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 01 16:39:25 myhost kill[20174]: kill: cannot find process ""
Mar 01 16:39:25 myhost systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 01 16:39:25 myhost systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Mar 01 16:39:25 myhost systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Mar 01 16:39:25 myhost systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Mar 01 16:41:29 myhost systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Mar 01 16:41:29 myhost httpd[20195]: httpd: Syntax error on line 185 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_ident.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_ident.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Mar 01 16:41:29 myhost systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 01 16:41:29 myhost kill[20197]: kill: cannot find process ""
Mar 01 16:41:29 myhost systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 01 16:41:29 myhost systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Mar 01 16:41:29 myhost systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Mar 01 16:41:29 myhost systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

Comment: You'll need to post your httpd.conf file, or whatever other conf files your modules are configured in. Also, while you might be able to just move those modules over, I give it about a 10% chance of working (never tried it, obviously). I do not recommend thinking about this - get your packages from repos.

Comment: Why is httpd.conf needed? In the logs posted about, its mod_authz_default.so is missing (and others). At least getting help to download one of it would be enough so I could fix the other modules myself.

Comment: First, because you said it was from an old server. Those config files get updated quite a bit from version to version, and I wanted to take inconsistencies due to this into consideration. As far as searching for a package based on its files, have you tried rpm.pbone.net or rpmfind.net? They're pretty exhaustive.

Comment: I was only concerned about the line `load module module_name.so` which is not invalid. So the next thing is that the module is missing and then we can't find it. Anyway I just found out that `mod_authn_default` and `mod_authz_default` is removed from 2.4. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/upgrading.html

Comment: For `mod_ident.so` I downloaded the source and compiled it.

Answer (score 3):

It seems these modules have been removed from `apache 2.4`: mod_authn_default, mod_authz_default, mod_mem_cache. [Refer apache upgrade doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/upgrading.html)

For `mod_ident.c` and other modules I downloaded the source from GitHub and compiled it.

Example:

```
[root@myhost ~]# wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/omnigroup/Apache/master/httpd/modules/metadata/mod_ident.c

[root@myhost ~]# apxs -a -i -c  mod_ident.c
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search on server centos 7 mod_cache_disk instead of mod_disk_cache. As you can see on this image link: https://prnt.sc/10jpipm

Comment: I can't edit the post right now, but in case the link goes down, https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6xD9.png might continue to work in the future.